# Database update error No Value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access

I was trying to use the update command to update my database at ms access and there
is an error of  No Value given for one or more required parameters whenever i try to execute it.

This is my code

```
private void btnupdate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ShopRecords.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ShopRecords SET ProductDescription = '" +tbproductdescrip.Text + "' WHERE (ID= " + tbupdate.Text + ")", con);

            con.Open();
            ad.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
         catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `tbproductdescrip` and `tbupdate` are user input fields, you should watch out for SQL injections.

Comment: What are the values of `tbproductdescrip.Text` and `tbupdate.Text`?

Comment: Its a text box for the user to key in and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following the next structure:

```
try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...", con);
            cmd.Transaction = tran;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tran.Commit();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
```

also, a good example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction.commit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: erm whats the cs in new OleDbConnection(cs))?

Comment: the connectionString. In your case "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ShopRecords.accdb"

Comment: Both of the datagridview and ms acess database didnt got updated

Comment: Make sure both tbproductdescrip.Text and tbupdate.Text are not NULL

Comment: i tried entering values in both the textboxes and it still does not work.

Comment: Test a particular case of the query in SQL Server (or whatever you are using) eg.: UPDATE ShopRecords SET ProductDescription = 'test' WHERE ID= 1 .If this is working, try printing the query that you are actually sending, and test that one also.You may also want to check if the columns and table name are corect.

Comment: Oh sorry i just found out that i had ID instead of RecordID 
thanks for your help (Y)

Comment: Re: "you have to start a transaction and commit it" - Actually, no, a transaction is not required to perform a single UPDATE. The problem was a malformed SQL statement, not the lack of a transaction.